# Customize React app build for different Firebase projects (environments)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a web app using React with a Firebase backend.
I want to  be able to deploy my app on different environments (staging, prod). To do this, I have added my app to 2 different Firebase projects, one for each environment.

What I want to be able to do is to deploy slightly different cloud functions depending on which environment I am deploying to. I want to automate all this for CI/CD.

Is there a way to specify different `functions/` folders for each Firebase project, or is my only option to have a script that moves the correct cloud functions code to the `functions/` folder on deploy? Similarly, how can I have different Firestore rules for each environment?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your option, as clarified in the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#deploy_functions), is to add the following lines into your firebase.json file to specify different paths.

```
"functions": {
  "source": "another-folder"
}
```

Since the [firebase.json](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#the_firebasejson_file) is individual for each project, with this lines, you should be able to set a different folder for each one of them, so they reference different files for your functions.

Regarding Firestore rules, due to the fact that they are in separate projects, you can access the Firestore Console and configure the security rules there. Each project will have their only set of rules for you to configure. You can get more information on how to structure them in this article [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure).

Let me know if the information helped you!